# Miscrosoft VS C++ linking error when building for 64bit version

Tags: c++, linker

I am using Visual Studio 2005.
I am able to build 32bit without issue. But when I am building 
64bit version, I am getting below linking error:

```
1>QALPROC.exp : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "const CustomMessageException::`vftable'" (??_7CustomMessageException@@6B@)
1>QALPROC.exp : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "const DBException::`vftable'" (??_7DBException@@6B@)
1>QALPROC.exp : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "const Exception::`vftable'" (??_7Exception@@6B@)
1>QALPROC.exp : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "const FileExportLoadException::`vftable'" (??_7FileExportLoadException@@6B@)
1>QALPROC.exp : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "const PMemoryException::`vftable'" (??_7PMemoryException@@6B@)
1>QALPROC.exp : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "const ReportsLoadingException::`vftable'" (??_7ReportsLoadingException@@6B@)
```

Comment: Are you using any libraries? You probably just haven't setup the libraries you are linking to in the 64 build mode.

Comment: Thanks, I did not use those class/function explicitly. so I think vftable is in some of microsoft library but I do not know which one.

Comment: `vftable` is the pointer to the **virtual functions table**, which stores pointers to virtualized functions for every object. In my opinion - you must be missing the base class, but I"m not sure, so didn't answer.

Comment: I tried a lot of things but I am still have 2 linking error left. 1>QALPROC.exp : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "const DBException::`vftable'" (??_7DBException@@6B@)
1>QALPROC.exp : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "const Exception::`vftable'" (??_7Exception@@6B@).   Can someone help to point out which library is responsible for vftable in VS 2005?